# Why won't my Nikon 1 V1 shoot outside for long-exposure after dark?

Tags: camera-settings, long-exposure, nikon-1, nikon-v1

So I'm trying to use a Nikon 1 V1 (yes I know it's an ancient camera!) for taking long exposure photos of the night sky. I have a wide angle lens and have set the mode to M; using a remote in 'time' mode I can take long-exposure pictures inside in the light fine, but when I go outside, point the camera at the night sky and press the remote the shutter doesn't open (all I get is a little red outline box on the screen). I think the camera thinks there isn't enough light. How do I force it to open the shutter?

Comment: Are you using Manual exposure or Manual focus? You need to use both Manual exposure and Manual focus.

Answer (score 1):

The red box means the camera cannot confirm focus. In modes AF-S and AF-A the shutter will not release unless the camera believes it is in focus.

Use focus lock (focus/recompose), or another focus mode. AF-F, AF-C, and Manual allow shutter release without focus confirmation.

Comment: Great, I'll try that! Thanks

Comment: @calyptorhynchus, if it works, consider [accepting this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) as a better way to say thanks. :)

Comment: Sure, haven't had a chance to try it yet (cloudy nights).